# Limitations to functions declared as `extern "C"`? C++ features still usable?

Tags: c++, c, language-features, extern

Does `extern "C"` do something more besides specifying an identifier should not be mangled?

Are C++ features available in functions that have been declared as `extern "C"`?

Answer (score 2):

It only affects the name mangling so that the external visibility is clear to other applications.

Comment: But can they still be overloaded? Or can they return C++ objects?

Comment: @H2CO3 - they will not be overloaded, e.g. I will be doing the overloading manually, but the point about returning C++ objects applies.

Comment: `extern "C"` _may_ also affect calling convention and it certainly affects visibility and name clashes between different namespaces.

Comment: No they cannot be overloaded, the standard says so.

Answer (score 1):

`extern "C"` does **not** mean compile as C code. It means **only** that the function should be compiled so that it can be called from C code; what that actually affects is implementation-dependent. Anything you can do in C++ is fine inside such a function, including throwing exceptions.

Comment: I realize it is a bit late, but what about templates? They cannot possibly work inside of an extern declaration, since it prohibits name mangling?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't throw exceptions from them, but otherwise you can implement the body of an `extern "C"` function with as many C++ features as you like.

This is perfectly fine:

```
MyObject myobj;
extern "C" { 
    int myfunc(char *c) 
    {    // c++ features used here
        std::string s = myobj.method(....
    }
}
```

Comment: What about exceptions that are being handled by the framework I use - Qt?

Comment: The exceptions shouldn't cross the `extern "C"` boundary, since you can't be sure the caller can handle them, or even if the caller is written in C++.